# Apache NiFi - ScanContent dictionary format not working

Tags: dictionary, binary, format, apache-nifi

I'm trying to run a ScanContent processor on Apache Nifi, and whilst I can get the processor to run when scanning a text file, and using a .txt dictionary file with the search terms contained in it (and delimited by a newline character), I cannot get it to run when searching a file using the binary type of the processor for the dictionary file.

I am unsure whether I am simply using the wrong format for the binary dictionary file, or whether it needs to be encoded differently. I couldnt find any example dictionaries anywhere online that would be of any use (most things were related to the ScanAttributes instead).

The format of my dictionary file is:

(inside a .txt file)

32 00001001001000010000100001000000\n

The requirements according to the documentation are that the dictionary terms need to be a 4 byte integer, followed by the binary search term.

Does anyone have any experience of using this processor with a binary dictionary that might be able to help specify the format?

Answer (score 2):

A binary dictionary file would typically be generated as the output of another program.  There is an example in the [ScanContent unit tests](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.1.2/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/TestScanContent.java#L57) for how to accomplish this in Java:

```
@Test
public void testBinaryScan() throws IOException {
    // Create dictionary file.
    final String[] terms = new String[]{"hello", "good-bye"};
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (final DataOutputStream dictionaryOut = new DataOutputStream(baos);) {
        for (final String term : terms) {
            final byte[] termBytes = term.getBytes("UTF-8");
            dictionaryOut.writeInt(termBytes.length);
            dictionaryOut.write(termBytes);
        }
        final byte[] termBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        final Path dictionaryPath = Paths.get("target/dictionary");
        Files.write(dictionaryPath, termBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
...
```